# Prevent process leak on LAMP environment

Tags: php, javascript, apache, magento

I work with Magento applications,  and i'm on kind of situation:

When user load some stores that have mutch information/jquery need lot of server process, if the user refresh the store mutch times pressing F5 the server get too mutch slow and difficult to use the store.

I need prevent this F5 'hack' slow my server, what i can do?? I think some kind of javascript/php solution.

But i want you opnion.

Ty all in advance.

Comment: I'm open to new ideas to solve this.

Comment: can u cache  the page or query?

Comment: Yes i can, but how it'll help-me with processing/processor leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found something.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/iosec/

Do the job

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle this serverside. Depending on your PHP/webserver installation, you could limit the number of concurrent requests.